# Error callback for a Task type in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I was wondering whats the error callback for a `Task` in C#.

For example : In **JavaScript** you have two callbacks for a promise.

```
obj.save().then(function(){
   //success
}, function(){
   //error
});
```

Whats the concept in C# with async/await.

```
Task task = obj.SaveAsync();
```

Where is the error callback in `Task`?

P.S : I'm migrating from JavaScript to C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are various options:

- You could use `Task.ContinueWith`, specifying the error callback using `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`
- You could await the task and just catch the exception which will be unwrapped accordingly:

  ```
  try
  {
      await obj.SaveAsync();
  }
  catch (BadStuffHappenedException e)
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```